# Как обрабатывать ошибки?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Использую модуль https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap-simple

Не понимаю как отлавливать ошибки и обрабатывать самому. Для примера при подключении, если креды неправильные то вылетает просто "Error: LOGIN invalid credentials or IMAP is disabled"

Если оборачивать в try catch код с подключением, то всё-равно не срабатывает.

В документации есть такое:

> Connect to an Imap server. Upon successfully connecting to the Imap
> server, either calls the provided callback with signature (err,
> connection), or resolves the returned promise with connection, where
> connection is an instance of ImapSimple.

Только как использовать не понимаю, он же падает с ошибкой раньше, функция эта не вызывается. Да и написано странно, то первым идет connection, то err, как аргументы вдруг так местами могут поменяться.

Пример кода с try catch, не перехватывает ошибку, скрипт падает

```
try {
    imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
      console.log('connect' );  
    
      // if(err)
      // {
      //     console.log(err);
      //     return;
      // }
     
      connection.end();
      console.log('end');
    
    }) 
    
  
  }catch(e)
  {
      console.log("Error "+e )
  }
```

Comment: Покажите как вы вызываете функцию и как пишите `try..catch`. Код вставлять надо как текст

Comment: Обновил в посте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо почитать как надо ловить ошибки у асинхронных функций. `Try..catch` не ловят ошибки из асинхронных функций. В вашем случае можно использовать синтаксис [then..catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch):

```js
imaps.connect(config)
.then(function (connection) {
  console.log('connect');     
  connection.end();
  console.log('end');
})
.catch((e) => {
  console.error(e);
})
```

Comment: Понял, я кстати пробовал подобное, но результат получал ровно такой же с обычной ошибкой, возвращал в лог просто объект с ошибкой, и не увидел разницы, подумал что не работает...

Comment: @metamorfoza Бывает :)